# create binary matrix from data.frame

Tags: r, matrix, binary, dataframe

How can I create a binary matrix from a data.frame with two columns where the first column represents e.g. species and the other their region? The data.frame is in tall format as seen below

```
species region
species1 1
species1 2
species1 3
species2 2
species2 4
species2 5
species2 6
species3 1
species3 2
species4 5
species5 3
species5 4
```

And the matrix would have all unique species as rows and all unique regions as columns. The matrix would be filled with `1s` for species present and `0s` for species absent, as below

```
         1  2  3  4  5  6
species1 1  1  1  0  0  0
species2 0  1  0  1  1  1
species3 1  1  0  0  0  0
species4 0  0  0  0  1  0
species5 0  0  1  1  0  0
```

Any pointers would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the function `table` whose documentation is [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/table.html)

If your data.frame is `df`, you just have to do

```
table(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Dooh' embarrassingly easy.

Comment: I'm getting an error: `attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements`. Is there a way to do it with bigger dataframes?

Answer (score 3):

an other possibility :

```
xtabs(~species+region, data=tab)
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting and for an alternative solution.

Comment: xtabs fonction as table is dedicated to create contingency tables, you just have to indicate which lines and columns you want to cross